# How fork() function works in this program?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, process, fork

I'm having some trouble with this program. I know what a fork() function does. It is used to create a new process from an existing process. The new process is called the child process, and the existing process is called the parent. The parent returnes the child's pid and the child returns 0. That said, I find hard to understand what the two fork functions do in this program.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i,y,x=1;
    for (i=0;i<4;i++)
        if(x && fork())
        {
            y = i;
            x = 0;
        }
    if (x) y = i;
    fork();
    printf("%i\n",y);
}
```

Comment: The program makes no sense.

Comment: here is the output https://ideone.com/Q9oD7o

Comment: Though the program works, it still does not make much sense.

Comment: Look at the pids that are returned on the forks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original process opens up a process when it enters the loop's `if`. The child does not enter the `if` since `fork() == 0`. Now the parent has `x == 0` and no longer enters the following iterations' `if`s (short circuit `&&` prevent `fork`s).

**note:** short circuit `if(x && fork())` prevents from forking twice since `x == 0` => no need to evaluate `fork()` (true for all processes that forked once). A process that forked once never enters loop's `if` because `x == 0` from that point on.

What you get is each loop value twice because each new process forks once the following iteration and outside the loop right before the print. There are no forks other than the first for each spawned process in the loop.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i,y,x=1;
    for (i=0;i<4;i++)
        if(x && fork()) // only un-forked process (x=1) executes fork()
        {
            // only parent process (fork() != 0) execute this
            y = i;
            x = 0;
        }
    if (x) y = i; // set up i=4 for last forked process (has x=1)
    fork();
    printf("%i\n",y);
}
```

The process spawning process would look something like this:

[image: Forking a process and right before the last print]

**tip:** When investigating code like this you can add output statements (`printf`) or use a debugger.

Comment: Using a debugger with that many child processes is more difficult than writing down on a paper, what happens here.

Comment: I'm not sure, using conditional breakpoints you can see what each thread is doing. Depends how good you are with paper (I'm not).

Comment: @ReutSharabani : I think you're wrong, the parent process opens only one child in the loop since fork() will return a non zero value considered as true.

Comment: While looking to your scheme I noticed that p1 witch is the child of p0 becomes a parent for p11 and p2. Is this right? Is it still p0's child, it still returns its PID to p0? Another question: p1 gets p11's PID and p11 returns 0. Is this right?

Comment: Each process `fork`s only in it's first iteration. After that iteration `x=0` and it no longer `fork`s. This means each process spawns one process and then skips all following iterations. In general, `fork` returns 0 in the child process and the child's pid to the parent process.

Answer (score 2):

First assert that: fork don't fail. That is not true, but more simple

if (x && fork())
  -> is true if x == 1 and if the fork return for the father
     then false.
So the child will create a child too (except the last one) but the
father just create one child.

After the loop you have 1 + 4 new process.
This 5 processus do the last fork(), you have 10 process.

The output result is not deterministic because of the scheduling of tasks.

Comment: It's just the order of the output that is non deterministic. The result is always the same: Every number in the interval [0,4] is printed two times. Each time from a different process.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can learn something from this program, when you look at the pids the forks return and estimate from that, which fork produces what output:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i,y,x=1;
    pid_t p,c;
    for (i=0;i<4;i++)
        if(x && 0 != (p=fork()))
        {
            y = i;
            c = p;
            x = 0;
        }
    if (x) y = i;
    p=fork();
    printf("%i %d %d\n",y, p, c);
}
```

For example I get this output:

```
0 24413 24412
0 0 24412
2 24417 24416
1 24415 24414
1 0 24414
3 24419 24418
2 0 24416
3 0 24418
4 24420 0
4 0 0
```

The first line is the child of the first child, the next line is the first child itself and so on. The last line is the parent.

Think over that and you can learn how fork works.

*Err, sorry, I was completely wrong, nearly: fork returns a positive pid to the parent, not to the child of course. So each line with positive p and c is the parent and so on. I leave the rest to figure out for you.*